# Display on Webpage Number of iPhone app downloads

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I would like to put on a webpage how many downloads of an iPhone app have happened.

I would like this to be automatic. By the way, I built the app.

Is this possible? Is there a JSON REST API I should know about?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to be an enterprise application, hosted on your website.  **If the iPhone app is in the Itunes Store, this is not possible.**

If it is on your website, then making a counter is pretty easy.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997482/how-to-create-file-download-counter) Stackoverflow post.

You can of course find the number of downloads of your app in Itunes Connect for your personal app, but this would be of no use to an automatic counter.

There is also a way to roughly estimate the amount of downloads based on the application rank.  See this [paper](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1924044) (d_iPad=9,525*rank^(-0.903) d_iPhone=52,511*rank^(-0.944)), although the methods might change based on the number of apps in the App store.