# php - what kind of download counter big websites companies have?

Tags: php, download, counter

I am developing in php and trying to implement a download counter to count the times that users downloaded my application..
I also read the following topics:

[Best way to implement a download counter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441618/best-way-to-implement-a-download-counter)

[Best way to count file downloads on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158124/best-way-to-count-file-downloads-on-a-website)

and found nothing useful enough..

What I would like to ask is: what kind of download counter the big companies implement? is it when the user cancels the download doesn't count?

Is it even possible - to count file downloads, and remove 1 from the count if the user canceled the download?

I already have a script that works great - but only when the file is 1MB or upper, when its less than a 1MB and a user cancels the download - the download still counts..

Thanks in advanced,
Din.

Comment: I'm sure everyone implements their own solution.  This isn't rocket surgery.  Show us your code that works great but doesn't, and perhaps we can suggest an improvement to it so that it works all of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody cares about canceled downloads (and in fact, bigger number looks cooler for management & users).

It is just counted via dummy redirect/logs analyzing.

No rocket science.

Comment: Thanks BarsMonster - thats what I wanted to hear :)